# ADX Studio - How to find the URL of a portal?

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

Is there a way from with Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise that has ADX Studio 7.2 installed to see the IIS site associated with a portal.

Settings->Portals->Websites lists what I'd expect to see, but I can't find anyway to see the URL or ISS details associated with the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following entities, its often found there.

- Web Notification.
- Website Bindings.
- Website.

Comment: Website Bindings ended up with the information I wanted, but I was thrown as there were 6 entries with only 2 sites.

Comment: @MattDuFeu, sounds normal. fwiw, you will want to setup the web notifications for the site to work properly. https://www.google.com/search?q=adxstudio+web+notification&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab